# xtsktest - overwriting the input model

Tags: sas, stata, panel, random-effects

I am working with panel random effect models and I need to perform Galvao test to check the normality of residuals (even if I am aware that normality shouldn't be an issue as explained by Professor Wooldridge: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1569107-normality-of-residuals-in-random-effects-model).

I found that for Galvao there is an useful command in Stata: `xtsktest` (https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/127687/1/cedlas-wp-178.pdf). However, `xtsktest` command can only be deployed right after estimating the model by using `xtreg re`.

Is it possible to overwrite the coefficients returned by `xtreg` command and then run `xtsktest` on my modified model?

I need to do this because, unfortunately, my reference model is estimated in SAS and the coefficients returned by `xtreg` are slightly different. Sadly, using model coefficients estimated in SAS is a requirement that I have to comply with.

Given such premises, any solution would be really appreciated.

P.S.
I tried to use the command `estimates save` but I wasn't able to understand how to manipulate this output (.ster file). Then, I managed to overwrite the matrix `e(b)` but `xtsktest` does not recognize this modified coefficient matrix and seems to take the same input as before